# No login screen after boot without external monitor

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, display, screen, intel-graphics

I've had this issue on multiple ubuntu based distros, the most recent being elementaryOS Luna.

Basically, I keep my laptop plugged into a 1280x1024 monitor at home. Whenever my laptop is powered off and the monitor is unplugged (for example, when I take it to class in the morning and it is already off) I am not presented with a login screen. I can see the POST screen as well as the boot-splash, but then the screen goes blank (but the backlight remains on).

Is there another fix other than simply adjusting my display configuration before shutting down? My laptop has a 2nd gen i3 in it and no other graphics card.

**EDIT**: I should add that even with the monitor connected, I can no longer see any login screen or switch to any VT. This happened before on a different distro, and I had to re-image my linux partition.

Comment: I haven't experienced this issue at all with Ivy Bridge on recent Ubuntu rleases running Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try, unplugging the monitor first and then shutdown the laptop?

Comment: When I'm already in my linux partition I make sure I do this. The problem is that if I need to quickly grab my laptop and it is already powered down, I didn't have the chance to properly disconnect the monitor. There has to be a better way than to disconnect it before every shutdown...